# Powershell Run Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

hello im trying to open an excel document then open an excel Macro Document, then have powershell run the specific macro that i want and let the macro do its magic and call it a day.

the script i have is this:

```
# start Excel 
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application  

#open file 
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ExcelWorkbook.xlsm' 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)  

#make it visible (just to check what is happening) 
$excel.Visible = $true  

#access the Application object and run a macro 
$app = $excel.Application 
$app.Run("Macro")
$excel.Quit()     

#Popup box to show completion - you would remove this if using task scheduler 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell $wshell.Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x1)
```

So my issue is im getting the error "all macros may be disabled"
what code do i use to make them enabled, i'm having issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

$app it's not defined, so try to replace **$app.Run("Macro")** with **$Excel.Run("Macro")**

Comment: It is actually, the question formatting was off.

Comment: Hello Elio, i changed that and im still getting the error "Cannot run macro" "all macros maybe disabled"

Comment: The workbook opens when you run the powershell script? The Trust Center settings in Excel is well configured? Post the entire srcipt error message. Share your workbook. in Dropbox or something similar.